# Python dictionary comprehension checking if something doesn't exist and setting a value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
old_dict = {"language":"english","gender":"female","job":"ceo"}
```

The only keys i'm interested in are
"language","job","hobby"

Filtering out using this logic only works for the keys that exist in my original dictionary.

```
   dict_you_want = { your_key: old_dict[your_key]  for your_key in your_keys if your_key in your_keys }
```

How can I alter this code to add conditions, if the key doesn't exist to set a null/none value to the key.

```
your_keys = ["language","job"]
```

The output i'm looking for is

```
{"language":"english","job":"ceo","hobby":None}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{ key:old_dict.get(key,None) for key in ["language","job", "hobby"]}
```

output:

```
{'hobby': None, 'job': 'ceo', 'language': 'english'}
```

Comment: `None` is the default